# Not able to start/access Klov Server at http://localhost for extent reports - Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: automation, extentreports

I'm new to klov reports and have downloaded the klov jar from  http://extentreports.com/community/0 and tried running klov-server (klov-0.2.0.jar) following the instruction at https://github.com/anshooarora/klov (java -jar klov-0.2.0.jar), however I'm getting below error and not able to start the klov server (http://localhost:portNo)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN0LO.png)

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-13 09:09:08.298 ERROR 40212 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

[Refer - Error Screenshot here]

1. Mongodb 3.2 running and listening on port 27017
2. klov application.properties file reside in the same folder as klov-0.2.0.jar
3. Have tried different ports for Klov (80, 90, 2571,1337), but all giving the same error as in description
4. Running it on windows 10, with application.properties settings as below:

---

```
# klov
application.name=Klov
server.host=localhost
server.port=90

# data.mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=klov

# data.rest
spring.data.rest.basePath=/rest
spring.data.rest.default-page-size=6

# redis, session
#use.redis.session.store=false
#spring.redis.host=localhost
#spring.redis.port=6379
#spring.redis.ssl=false
#spring.redis.database=0
#spring.session.store-type=redis
#server.session.timeout=-1

# users
server.admin.name=klovadmin
server.admin.key=$2a$10$I/5TFi6BrHChUghTZEZfCO82txzu8L5brcK0CxhS3m.V6glfj2vZe

# storage
file.storage.location=./upload/reports/

# schedulers
scheduler.jobs.enabled=false
# automatically delete older builds
# default is -1 (keep all)
# this count must be greater than 0 for this scheduler to work
# scheduled to run daily at 12:00AM
scheduler.job.builds.retain.count=-1

# mail
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.port=
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.test-connection=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using a mail server, start with the following properties:

```
# klov
application.name=Klov
server.host=localhost
server.port=80

# data.mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=klov

# data.rest
spring.data.rest.basePath=/rest
spring.data.rest.default-page-size=6

# redis, session
use.redis.session.store=false
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.ssl=false
spring.redis.database=0
spring.session.store-type=redis
server.session.timeout=-1

# users
server.admin.name=klovadmin
server.admin.key=$2a$10$I/5TFi6BrHChUghTZEZfCO82txzu8L5brcK0CxhS3m.V6glfj2vZe

# storage
file.storage.location=./upload/reports/

# schedulers
scheduler.jobs.enabled=false
# automatically delete older builds
# default is -1 (keep all)
# this count must be greater than 0 for this scheduler to work
# scheduled to run daily at 12:00AM
scheduler.job.builds.retain.count=-1

# mail
#spring.mail.host=
#spring.mail.port=
#spring.mail.username=
#spring.mail.password=
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.test-connection=false
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply taking the mail server details worked, however I've to change the port to 90. I was able to start klov server localhost:90 but ended in error "freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: Java method "com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color.byStatus(String)" threw an exception when invoked on com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color object "com.aventstack.klov.viewdefs.Color@7f5bb7"
----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
        - Failed at: ${Color.byStatus(project.lastReport.s...  [in template "project.select.ftl" at line 46, column 117]"

Comment: Hmm what is your ExtentReports version?

Comment: thanks again for your quick reply. Above error is displayed on the console window on which klov server (klov-0.2.0.jar) is running, while I enter credentials on localhost:90. I'vent ran the extent reports as yet, which is actually using nuget package ExtentReports by AventStack 3.1.3 in VS.net. 
Just saw at http://extentreports.com/community/ that there is extentreports-4.0.0.jar, not sure if I've to also install/run that too, before accessing klov server? It's very hard to find clear info around on internet, thanks again for your help @foursyth

Comment: Klov 0.2 only works with ExtentReports 4.0.0+, which is not available for .NET.  You can download Klov 0.1.1 which works with your version from http://extentreports.com/community/

Comment: thanks again @foursyth. extentreports.com/community page does not allow users to download previous versions of Klov (i.e Klov 0.1.1), the only version available to download is 0.2.0 and this from url https://github.com/extent-framework/klov-server/tree/master/0.2.0, I would apprecaite help around getting Klov-0.1.0.jar?

Comment: Please check the link again at the very bottom of the page.  You will see extentreports-3.1.5 and klov-server-0.1.1.  http://extentreports.com/community/

Comment: hi @foursyth, I can access  klov-server-0.1.1 on the community page now and I was able to generate reports on the local server - thanks for resolving this issue so quickly, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Just a small update for anyone following this thread. .NET support is being considered and I will update the final decision of the team in a few days.